# ASP.NET Gridview does not show in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to see my gridview in the page, no matter what I change. I have used Datasource and Databind, Visible is True, I am thinking at least I should see only the table but nothing. Also I am really sorry that I did not translate this, some things are in Spanish but I think you will understand the context despite the names are in spanish. If this is a problem I can edit and translate.
Thanks.

**aspx file:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master" CodeBehind="ListarRemateCerrado.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Interfaz.ListarRemateCerrado" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<p>CIERRE DE REMATE</p>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstRemates" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:GridView ID="grvRemates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="grvRemates_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnSorting="grvRemates_Sorting" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID Remate" SortExpression="Remate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Remate") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comision Rematador" SortExpression="Comision">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblComision" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comision")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView><br />
    <asp:GridView ID="grvRemateSeleccionado" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRefrescar" runat="server" Text="Refrescar" OnClick="btnRefrescar_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnVolver" runat="server" Text="Volver" OnClick="btnVolver_Click" CausesValidation="false" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCorrecto" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </asp:Content>
```

**aspx.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Dominio;

namespace Interfaz
{
   public partial class ListarRemateCerrado : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        lstRemates.DataSource = Agencia.Instancia().devolverRemates();
        lstRemates.DataTextField = "Datos";
        lstRemates.DataValueField = "numero";
        lstRemates.DataBind();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Remate> ordenada = Agencia.Instancia().devolverRemates();
            ordenada.Sort(new Remate.OrdenarXRemate());
            Session["sortedView"] = ordenada;
            BindData(ordenada);
            Session["filtro"] = "numero";
            Session["direccion"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
    }

    protected void btnRefrescar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Remate> ordenada = Agencia.Instancia().devolverRemates();
        ordenada.Sort(new Remate.OrdenarXRemate());
        Session["sortedView"] = ordenada;
        BindData(ordenada);
        Session["filtro"] = "numero";
        Session["direccion"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
    }

    protected void btnVolver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("MenuPrincipalAdmin.aspx");
    }

    protected void BindData(List<Remate> r)
    {
        lstRemates.DataSource = r;
        lstRemates.DataBind();
    }

    protected void grvRemates_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Remate> ordenada = (List<Remate>)Session["sortedView"];
        if (e.SortExpression == "Remate") ordenada.Sort(new Remate.OrdenarXRemate());
        if (e.SortExpression == "Comision") ordenada.Sort(new Remate.OrdenarXComision());

        if (e.SortExpression == Session["filtro"].ToString().Trim())
        {
            SortDirection aux = (SortDirection)Session["direccion"];
            if (SortDirection.Ascending == aux)
            {
                Session["direccion"] = SortDirection.Descending;
                ordenada.Reverse();
            }
            else
            {
                Session["direccion"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }
        Session["filtro"] = e.SortExpression;
        Session["sortedView"] = ordenada;
        BindData(ordenada);
    }

    protected void grvRemates_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grvRemates.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData((List<Remate>)Session["sortedView"]);
    }

    protected void grvRemates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CargarPaquete();
    }

    private void CargarPaquete()
    {
        GridViewRow row = grvRemates.SelectedRow;
        Label lbl = row.FindControl("lblRemate") as Label;
        int codigo = int.Parse(lbl.Text);

        grvRemateSeleccionado.DataSource = Agencia.Instancia().devolverLotesRemate(codigo);
        grvRemateSeleccionado.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nowhere set the call **databind** method for the grid,

```
 grvRemates.DataSource= Agencia.Instancia().devolverRemates();
 grvRemates.DataBind();
```

Comment: So simple, you damn genius. Thank you so much.